# py.test ImportError: cannot import name * on gitlab-ci unner

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

package layout:

```
    package/__init__.py
            abc.py
            test_abc.py
```

> cd pakage && py.test -s -v

keep getting

```
ImportError: cannot import name abc
```

I have tried use sys.path.insert(0, current_directory) but still in vain.
Any helps would be great ! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using virtual environment do this step as well.

`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:path/to/your/virtual_environment/bin` file

or just do

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/your/current_directory
```

All these commands needs to write in shell

Once you do this go to python shell

and write

```
import sys
sys.path
```

your current_directory should be in response list and you should be able to use your package